# iOS how can I use storyboard elements that don't exist in earlier versions of iOS?

Tags: ios7, ios9, xcode7, uistoryboard, compatibility

I have a project originally targeting iOS7 using a storyboard. I've added a UIStackView to a view controller and get an error that "UIStackView before iOS 9.0". The build fails because of this error.

**How can I keep my project as iOS7, while conditionally including newer storyboard elements from iOS9 if device supports them?**

I already have conditional code in the project that only runs on iOS8+, but how can I do something similar with a storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

The class UIStackView (and its software) is provided by iOS 9, but is not provided by iOS 8 or 7.  When the app tries to instantiate an object from the storyboard in iOS 8, it will fail because it cannot find the class.

The only ways around this:

- have different storyboards for different iOS vesions
- build a custom class that does the same thing. Then you can use it in the older versions of the iOS. You might find open source libraries that already do this for the class you want.